# inserting multiple sql query's from a table to another table through PHP

Tags: php

I have this table in with some rows and values in it, i get those values in my php page and user selects them and submits the same to insert the selected into another page.

So, here the main catch, 
I wrote a sql query with 3 input boxes in which one takes input number from user and multiplies it with other default number in input box 2(which get the value from table1)  and prints it out in input box 3.

I wrote JS code for it and it works fine. now i added php to it, in a way that input box 1 takes value directly from php table row and multiplies it with user inserted value in box2 and prints it in box 3

It still works fine even with multiple queries, cause i have made the id value of each box dynamic.

But the problem rises as when i try to submit the three input box values, it works fine for one query/when one row in table1 but when there are multiple queries, it only inserts the first query (3 input box values) and skips the rest of the queries.

My Php , Js, Html code goes as:

```
<?php 
   $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE value= '$value'";
   $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
   if ($result2->num_rows > 0) { 
   while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {   
?>

<input type="number" name="input1" form="checkout" class="input1" id="input1_<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row2['price']; ?>"> 
<input type="text" name="input2" class="input2"  id="input2_<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" value="0" >
<input type="text" name="output" class="output" form="checkout" id="output_<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" value="">

<form method="post" action="submit.php" id="checkout">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row2["id"]; ?>" name="id"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">
            <h4>Submit</h4>
        </button>
</form>
```

The submit page looks like this..

```
$input1 = $_POST['input1'];
$output = $_POST['output'];

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (input1, output)
VALUES ('$input1', '$output')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Now the problem is , it works fine inserting data from input1 and output boxes into tabll2 when there is only one query in table 1,
but when there are multiple queries in table 1, it only inserts the first query leaving the rest untouched with no error.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Change your html name attribute to an array, This would help you handle  multiple inputs. Then in Php, loop through them

Comment: can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Then main reason is that all the text boxes for `input1` field have one name, then at the result there is only one variable `$_POST["input1"]`, so for other text boxes.

You must set an array-like names for your text boxes:

```
<?php 
   $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE value= '$value'";
   $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
   if ($result2->num_rows > 0) { 
?>
<form method="post" action="submit.php" id="checkout">
<?php
   while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {   
?>
<input type="number" name="input1-<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" form="checkout" class="input1" id="input1_<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row2['price']; ?>"> 
<input type="text" name="input2-<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" class="input2"  id="input2_<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" value="0" >
<input type="text" name="output-<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" class="output" form="checkout" id="output_<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" value="">
<?php
}
?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row2["id"]; ?>" name="id"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">
            <h4>Submit</h4>
        </button>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Then you must set the submit page:

```
<?php
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE value= '$value'";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {   
  $input1 = $_POST['input1-'.$row2['id']];
  $output = $_POST['output-'.$row2['id']];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (input1, output) VALUES ('$input1', '$output')";
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  }
  else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
}
?>
```